# Changing rows to become column headers - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, row, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get the following two columns from the below format

[image]

To this format

[image]

I've tried transposing (but that transposes the entire table (5/6 columns in the original data)
and when I've tried unpivoting that's also not worked.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I selected both columns and used the pivot column option.